How is ARR defined?
Suppose we invest 100 €.Year 1 we have a inflow of 100€,second year we have a inflow of 20€.If we want to calculate the ARR(accounting rate of return) we have to do we need to find the average of in flows for all the years we pay back or for all the years of the life of the investment? Is ARR equal to 1 or equal to 0.6?

Perhaps you should consult the definition of ARR.
